# Multiple arguments in MySQL raw() query in DJango-Python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need to find a person when he enters his mobile number or email in the login form.
My raw() query goes like this:

```
user = Users.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM main_users WHERE mobile  = %s OR email = %s',[login_id],[login_id])
```

But I am always getting a error:

```
Exception Value: not enough arguments for format string
```

So, what's the correct format for getting this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by any of these two ways as already said above:

```
from django.db.models import Q
users = User.objects.filter(Q(mobile=login_id) | Q(email=login_id))
```

or by using raw() method:

```
user = Users.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM main_users WHERE mobile  = %s OR email = %s',[login_id,login_id])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put parameters under the same list:

```
user = Users.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM main_users WHERE mobile  = %s OR email = %s',
                         [mobile, email])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a raw query here.

```
users = User.objects.filter(Q(mobile=login_id) | Q(email=login_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

The upper solutions were not working for me. I solved by this in Python 3

```
user = Users.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM main_users WHERE mobile  = '%s' OR email = '%s' " %(mobile, email))
```